# Allocate and initialize matrix using sizeof

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic

Is it possible to allocate dynamically and initialize (and free) a matrix (or others multidimensional arrays) using **sizeof operator** instead of indexes and "standard" pointer arithmetic?

I've tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLUMNS 4

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    char **v;

    if((v = malloc(ROWS*sizeof(char*)))==NULL)
        return -1;
    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        if((*(v + i * sizeof(char*)) = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char)))==NULL)
            return -2;
    }

    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            *(*(v + i * sizeof(char*)) + j * sizeof(char)) = 'a' + i * COLUMNS + j;
            printf("%c",*(*(v + i * sizeof(char*)) + j * sizeof(char)));
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        free(*(v + i * COLUMNS * sizeof(char)));
    }
    free(v);

    return 0;
}
```

but it generates a core dump (SIGSEGV at line 24 (v[1][0])). I believe the problem is in the allocation (**maybe** for the allocation v[1], v[2]... v[ROWS] malloc goes to write on the memory first allocated). Precisely, what is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `*(v + i * sizeof(char *))` is equivalent to `v[i * sizeof(char *)]` or `*((unsigned char *) v +  i * sizeof(char *) * sizeof(char *)`.

In pointer arithmetic, the increment is performed in units of the pointee type, in this case `char *`.

If you want to compute the offset yourself just cast the pointer to `unsigned char *` but that,

1. Is absolutely redundant, except in some situations where you don't want the pointer to have a definite type and it's `void *`, in that case casting to `unsigned char *` and incrementing the exact number of bytes is OK.
2. There is no good reason for that to be a requirement, you don't use the `sizeof` operator because it's a requirement but instead because you need to.
3. It's error prone and you can easily cause *Undefined Behavior* as it happens with your code, which has something even more disturbing

   ```
   *(*(v + i * sizeof(char*)) + j * sizeof(char))
   ```

   In detail,

   1. There is no way that `sizeof(char)` will be different than `1`, it's like multiplying by *sin<sup>2</sup>(x) + cos<sup>2</sup>(x)*, it makes absolutely no sense.
   2. You are incrementing the pointer way beyond the allocated space, becauseof the first point again.

Comment: For the first question (Is it possible to allocate...)?

Comment: @SimoneBonato Why do you want to do that, why do you insist in doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Is it the wrong way? I thought it was a way not advisable, but not completely wrong.

Comment: I use sizeof(char) beacuse it can easily become sizeof(other).

Comment: It's like trying to solve a physics problem, and choosing the worst frame of reference that is possible. We all know that the solution exists in any inertial frame of reference, but we choose the one where the solution is simple, not where it's impossible.

Comment: It can't become `sizeof(other)` if you don't change it, and in that case use `sizeof(**v)`.

Comment: writing sin^2 + cos^2 instead of 1 can be of great help! :P

Comment: I know, but writing `sizeof(char)` is just annoying. I have solved some tricky trigonometric integrals with that :)

Comment: Do I have to use `*((unsigned char*)v + i * sizeof(char*))` for allocate and `*((unsigned char*)v + i * sizeof(char*) + j)` for access to char?